# Symfony: fatal error with JsonRequestTransformerListener in prod

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony

I use JsonRequestTransformerListener service to convert AngularJS request to normal request. In dev env it works fine, in prod env I have this error:

```
$ php5.3 index.php
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Qandidate\Common\Symfony\HttpKernel\EventListener\JsonRequestTransformerListener' not found in /home/a/appliveorg/thank/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 584
```

Comment: Did you clear the cache? `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: Clear cache, if it won't work, show us your AppKernel.php file. Maybe you are loading this class only in dev env.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov yes i did.

Comment: @Mr.Smith this class is service https://github.com/qandidate-labs/symfony-json-request-transformer

Comment: Are you trying to run this from the command line?